# binary variable sample values to population distribution

Tags: probability, sample, population

What seems like a very basic stats question, but yet I wouldn't know the answer and its quite hard to find. Here we go:

Say I have a population of 30 organizations. I want to know whether within this group the value of one binary variable tends to be A or B.

Say that I pick 5 organizations at random and find that for all these organizations the value of my binary variable is A. What does this tell me about, say, the likelihood that the value for all 30 organizations is A? Or that A is the value for at least some percentage (say, more than 50%) of the organizations? Is there a simple formula to calculate this?

Essentially I need a tool to help me determine: my sample size is big enough now to infer confidently (controversial choice of words, perhaps) that A is the rule, B the exception.

Comment: It’s tricky if you only observe one category (unless you observe that one category in 16 of 30 subjects, at which point you know it is the majority). Laplace’s rule of succession may be of interest for that task. However, it sounds like you are interested in a sample size calculation for a proportion variable, whether you observe all A or 4/5 as A rather than B. Is that correct?

Comment: A sample size calculation sounds accurate. Laplace's rule of succession I think comes close to what I would need, but given that I have a known population size my problem is somewhat more uncomplicated than the sunrise problem. Basically what I would like to know is: If the population is 30 and all 5 observations are A, what is the probability that, say, 70% or more of the population is A.